# Display empty value when there is no data on the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-table

I have table and query to select data from row to column like this:

```
 id  |  type    | data
-----------------------
  1  |  Name    | John
  1  |  Gender  | Male
  1  |  Code    | 1782
  2  |  Name    | Dave
  2  |  Gender  | Male
```

Query:

```
select a.id, a.data as [Name], b.data as [Gender], c.data as [Code]
from table1 a join table1 b on a.id = b.id
              join table1 c on b.id = c.id
where a.type = 'Name' and b.type = 'Gender' and c.type = 'Code'
```

Result:

```
  id |  Name   | Gender | Code  
 ------------------------------
  1  |  John   |  Male  | 1782
```

In this case id number 2 with the name 'Dave' doesn't have a 'Code' so it wont appear in the result. How can I still display the result with empty data or NULL on the 'Code' table so it will have result like this:

```
  id |  Name   | Gender | Code  
 ------------------------------
  1  |  John   |  Male  | 1782 
  2  |  Dave   |  Male  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression instead of `JOIN`s :

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'Name' THEN a.data ELSE '' END) AS [Name],
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'Gender' THEN a.data ELSE '' END) AS [Gender],
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'Code' THEN a.data ELSE '' END) AS [Code]
FROM table1 a
WHERE
    a.type IN('Name', 'Gender', 'Code')
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thanks it is correct, just a correction in line MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = ...) not a.data.

Comment: @Reusellmy, good eyes ;).. i've corrected, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.id, a.data as [Name], b.data as [Gender], c.data as [Code]
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.id = b.id and b.type='Gender'
left join table1 c on b.id = c.id and c.type='Code'
where a.type = 'Name'
```

Comment: It is correct according to the question, but when empty value or null in the middle the rest of the data become null too.

Answer (score 1):

use a [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) query

```
select *
from   table1
       pivot
       (
           max(data)
           for type in ([Name], [Gender], [Code])
       ) p
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6cd13009e686ac12f18a8ca6334c1fa)